# OS X terminal 'split pane' different sessions

Tags: macos, terminal

I frequently use OS X terminal in maximized mode. But the problem is that I want to split it into 2 or more parts, having distinct terminal process in each pane.

Like this.

[image: this]

But apparently the 'split pane' command simply clones one process. Any ideas how can I make this work (desirably without *iterm2* or any other side terminal).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know you could split panes in Terminal. But, in recent versions of OS X, Terminal supports tabs (**Command+t** creates a new one). So, while it might not be ideal, you could set up four tabs and cycle through them to check on your processes. **Command+{** cycles to the left. **Command+}** cycles to the right.

Comment: Yeh, well, I know about tabs, but that's not exactly what I want, because I switch from one terminal to another frequently and I want to have each one of them in front of me.

Comment: This thread seems relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-do-split-panes-in-terminal-work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
# First install tmux
brew install tmux

# For mouse support (for switching panes and windows)
# Only needed if you are using Terminal.app (iTerm has mouse support)
Install http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php
Then install https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/

# More on mouse support http://floriancrouzat.net/2010/07/run-tmux-with-mouse-support-in-mac-os-x-terminal-app/

# Enable mouse support in ~/.tmux.conf
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on

# Install Teamocil to pre define workspaces
https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil

# See http://files.floriancrouzat.net/dotfiles/.tmux.conf for configuration examples
```

original gist here: https://gist.github.com/simme/1297707

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `tmux` or `screen`

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux
- https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html